# Topologically equivalent metric spaces is an equivalence relation

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations

I'm trying to prove that topological equivalence is an equivalence relation. Reflexivity was easy, and I'm sure transitivity is too, but I'm stuck on symmetry. My book's definition is that a metric space $(X,d_{1})$ is topologically equivalent to a metric space $(Y,d_{2})$ if there is a continuous bijection between them. But the inverse of a continuous bijection need not be continuous, so I'm not sure how to find a continuous bijection from $Y$ to $X$.

Continuity is given an epsilon-delta definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider the continuous bijection from $[0,\pi)$ to $S^1$ given by $t \mapsto (\cos t,\sin t)$. Both are metric spaces, but there is no continuous bijection in the reverse direction since $S^1$ is compact but $[0,\pi)$ is not.

You could alternatively define $(X,d)$ and $(Y,d')$ to be equivalent if there are continuous bijections in both directions. This still [doesn't make the spaces homeomorphic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30661/non-homeomorphic-spaces-that-have-continuous-bijections-between-them), but is certainly an equivalence relation.